# My next.js app goes blank after deploying on cPanel

Tags: reactjs, next.js, deployment, cpanel

I deployed my Next.js app on cPanel and its blank. It works fine locally. Here are the steps I followed :

1.First, I created a custom server.js in my root directory with the following code :

```
const { createServer } = require('http')
const { parse } = require('url')
const next = require('next')

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
const hostname = 'localhost'
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000

const app = next({ dev, hostname, port })
const handle = app.getRequestHandler()

app.prepare().then(() => {
  createServer(async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true)
      const { pathname, query } = parsedUrl

      if (pathname === '/a') {
        await app.render(req, res, '/a', query)
      } else if (pathname === '/b') {
        await app.render(req, res, '/b', query)
      } else {
        await handle(req, res, parsedUrl)
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('Error occurred handling', req.url, err)
      res.statusCode = 500
      res.end('internal server error')
    }
  }).listen(port, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err
    console.log(`> Ready on http://${hostname}:${port}`)
  })
})
```

2. Then I edited the package.json file to set the environment to production on the start script :

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production node server.js",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
```

3. npm run build and compress the following files :

[image: list of the files ready to be imported on cPanel File Manager]

4. Imported and extracted all in the File Manager Root Directory :

[image: Files imported in the File Manager]

5.Created my application on Setup Node.js App with the following information :

[image: NodeJs App information]

6. Stop Application - Run NPM install and then restart the application

After all these steps, my app is blank, and I don't know what I did wrong.

Here is a [Github link](https://github.com/Wiseard/nextjs-app) where you can see all the app code. I'm stuck since yesterday and I appreciate any help you can give me to resolve this problem. I know the issue is due to my app but I can't figure it out.

I hope all the information I provided could help you to understand.

Comment: Hi, did you ever get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

return `commonjs ${localRes.replace(/.*?next[/\\]dist/, "next/dist")}`;

replace with
//  below code  node_modules/next/dist/build/handle-externals.js

return `commonjs ${localRes.replace(/.*?next[/\\]dist/, "next/dist").replace(/\\/g, "/")}`

and make build it will work nextjs 14